# Rails 4 - Sortable Records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting

Im trying to make an app with Rails 4.

I'm trying to follow this tutorial on how to sort the model by column names:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/228-sortable-table-columns

The tutorial may be out of date.

I've tried to make my controller match the tutorial, as follows:

```
helper_method :sort_column, :sort_direction

  # GET /organisations
  # GET /organisations.json
  def index
    @organisations = Organisation.order(sort_column + " " + sort_direction)
  end

 def sort_column
      Organisation.column_names.include?(params[:sort]) ? params[:sort] : "title"
    end

    def sort_direction
      %w[asc desc].include?(params[:direction]) ? params[:direction] : "asc"
    end
```

Application_helper has:

```
module ApplicationHelper

    def sortable(column, title = nil)
      title ||= column.titleize
      css_class = column == sort_column ? "current #{sort_direction}" : nil
      direction = column == sort_column && sort_direction == "asc" ? "desc" : "asc"
      link_to title, {:sort => column, :direction => direction}, {:class => css_class}
    end
end
```

I add this to my organisations index show page:

```
<td><span class="intpolth"><%= sortable "name" %></span></td>
```

When I try this, I get the following error:

```
undefined method `sortable' for #<#<Class:0x007f9a3c54e0b0>:0x007f9a39efd460>
```

Can anyone see what's wrong? or know a better way to sort by column name?

Comment: There is no problem by learning your code. Please check the application_helper.rb file you've edited is your current project file.

Comment: Hey, you're right, I forgot to save it. Although when I click on the sortable header, nothing happens. The rows don't move based on the sorted column

Comment: its actually fine - all working. i had titlecased the label on the columns

Comment: It's okay. Good luck!